# Basic font-awesome does not load icon

Tags: font-awesome

Here is the code. It is very simple.

```
<i class="fal fa-chevron-left"></i>
```

Everything is copied from their official tutorial.

The link to codepen is here:

https://codepen.io/nicolasxu/pen/eLqNdp

css is included here:

[image]

Comment: Have you included font-awesome library into your head section? Check this: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started?using=web-fonts-with-css

Comment: yes, please see my updated question.

Comment: I referenced a pro verson of icon. You have to have pay to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to use the 'light' version of that icon, which is only available to Pro users on font-awesome (see here: https://fontawesome.com/icons/chevron-left?style=light). The only free version of that icon appears to be the `fas` one, or the 'solid' one.

The CSS you've linked into the codepen is the 'free' version CSS which is why it wouldn't show up there.